# Remove Text With Preg_Replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have some text like the following example:

```
Some Text Here
[code]Some link[/code]
Text
[code]Link[/code]
Other Text
[code]Another Link[/code]
Other Text1
```

I want to remove all the text above, under, and between the two code. Here's an example of the output I want:

```
[code]Some Link[/code]
[code]Link[/code]
[code]Another Link[/code]
```

I use `preg_replace` for removing text above the first Code, in this way:

```
$message = preg_replace('/(.*?)\[code/si','[code',$message, 1);
```

Can you help me to remove the other text, using `preg_replace`?

Comment: Have you tried using `preg_split` ?

Comment: what's the usage of preg_split?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
     preg_match_all('/(\[code\].*\[\/code\])/Usmi', $text, $res);
        $cnt = 0;
        foreach ($res as $val) {
          $cnt++;
          $message .= $val[$cnt] . "<br />";          
        }
     echo $message;
```

Comment: but i need to put the content of my text, back in my variable $message

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the solution of @Andreev a little more simple :

```
$text = "
Some Text Here
[code]Some link[/code]
Text
[code]Link[/code]
Other Text
[code]Another Link[/code]
Other Text1
";

$keywords = preg_match_all('/(\[code\].*\[\/code\])/Usmi', $text, $res);
print(implode($res[0]));
```

You can test it here : http://phptester.net/index.php?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can never have `[code] abc [code] def [/code] ghi [/code]`, try this:

```
do {
    $message = preg_replace("((?:\[code\].*?\[/code\])*).*?(?=\[code\]))is","$1",$message,-1,$c);
} while($c);
```